# Open webpage on default system browser using specific credentials

Tags: c#

As the title says, I want on my C# application, to click a button(for example), and in the default browser of the computer, this site will open, and sign in to it using specific credentials.

For example open Facebook, and sign in using the credentials that I saved in my form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are usually 2 ways to go about this.

1. Write a plugin that can get information from your application and use it on the website. It would be something similar to what KeePass (among others) uses.
2. Write your application to act like a web UI test automation tool.

Both of these options are beyond my realm of experience since I have not needed to do either one. If I need to interact with a website, I usually do it within a hosted WebBrowser control where I can get access to the DOM.